# Using article "the" when addressing a general category in an article

Tags: articles

I am writing an English paper; (actually translating into English from a Persian source), where the topic of "ending" in story writing is discussed. Due to frequent use of the term "story", can I use "the" before story? For example, in the following sentence:

> An ending is the last paragraph of a story, play, or a screenplay. In fictional literature, it is a description of the last part of the story describing the behavior, speech, and status of the heroes and the story’s atmosphere.

where, I am not talking about any particular story. As articles are not often used in Persian, it makes me confused in such cases whether to use a definite article or not, given the fact that "story" in the above text refers to a specific category of writing being discussed in the paper and that has been addressed several times in the same paper. That being said, is this "the" usage permissible?

Comment: There's nothing at all wrong with the articles in your quote, except that you should either say *"a story, a play, or a screenplay"* or *"a story, play, or screenplay"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you would the articles "a/an" when you are not referring to a specific thing but instead to any example in a group of things. You use "the" when referring back to a thing that is already specified either by you or by context.

> In fictional literature, it is a description of the last part of **the
>   story** describing the behavior, speech, and status of the heroes and
>   **the story’s** atmosphere.

Your first use of the phrase 'the story' isn't referring to a specific story, so *'a story'* is more appropriate. Your second use of this phrase is referring to a story that you specified in the first half of the sentence (when you said 'a story'), so *'the story'* is more appropriate.

Other example:

I saw **a** dog. **The** dog didn't have a collar.

Do you have **a** quarter I can borrow? I can return **the** quarter to you tomorrow.

(Note that these sentences are a bit weird because we should be using pronouns in the second sentences, but they are still valid)

Do you have **a** pencil I can borrow?

Do you have **the** homework I assigned yesterday?

Comment: This is a pretty good answer, but (as mentioned here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93834/usage-of-english-definite-article-when-referring-to-generic-word) _the_ can be used in a generic sense. I think "it is a description of the last part of the story" falls under that usage.

Comment: I definitely agree that your way sounds fine too for exactly that reason.